# libcrafter.so.0 not found in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to use the libcrafter in eclipse. I added the following parameters in the build settings of the project:

```
 -L/usr/local/lib`
 -lcrafter
 -lpcap
 -lpthread
```

and I added it to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`

I also did a `clean` and rebuild of the project,

but when I then run the program in eclipse, I get the following error:

`error while loading shared libraries: libcrafter.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

when compiling the program in command line with

`g++ SimpleCodeTester.cpp -o Simple -lpcap -lcrafter -lpthread -L/usr/share/lib/`

and executing everything works!?

Comment: Is it in /usr/local/lib or /usr/share/lib? It is strange that your -L flag doesn't match your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. What happens if you remove the -L line completely (it has a weird thingy at the end by the way)? Can you get eclipse to print its compilation line?

Comment: Sorry typo, its in /usr/local/lib (I had it right on my system already)...if a remove the -L in eclipse nothing changes, still the same error but it works without the -L in the command line